# How to correctly malloc a struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, realloc

Here is my full code, it looks like to work, but it's not working very well.
I would accept any code, that is working like this.

Firstly, the code works, but when I want to add the third name to the struct, it crashes.

Is there any other way to do this?

I need struct, because in the future, I want to add some other params, like age, average, gender, etc.

Please, help me out.

```
//The student table
typedef struct students {
    char name[50];
} students;

//Global params
int scount = 0;
students *s;

//Basic functions
void addNewStudent();

int main()
{
    int loop = 1;
    char in;
    int ch;
    printf("Willkommen.\n Wahlen Sie bitte von die folgenden Optionen:\n");
    while (loop)
    {
        printf("\t[1] Neue Student eingeben\n");
        printf("\t[9] Programm beenden\n");

        scanf(" %c", &in);
        while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n');
        switch (in)
        {
        case '1':
            addNewStudent();
            break;
        case '9':
            loop = 0;
            break;
        default: printf("------\nOption nicht gefunden.\n------\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    free(s);
    return 0;
}

void addNewStudent()
{
    int index = 0;
    if (scount == 0)
    {
        s = (students*)malloc(sizeof(students));
    }
    else
    {
        realloc(s, sizeof(students) * scount);
    }

    printf("Geben Sie Bitte die Name:\n");
    fgets(s[scount].name, sizeof(s[scount].name), stdin);

    while (s[scount].name[index] != '\n')
    {
        index++;
    }
    s[scount].name[index] = '\0';
    scount++;
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio.

Thanks for help!

Comment: What is supposed to do the code? What is the problem you are fighting with?

Comment: suggest change structure name to singular, i.e. student or Student

Comment: [Don't cast `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc): `s = malloc(sizeof(students));`

Comment: You're not recovering the pointer returned by `realloc`. Also, since you're incrementing `scount` after reallocating, you're always reallocating a size that's one struct too small.

Comment: @lurker: better still `s = malloc(sizeof *s);` - that protects against changing the type pointed to.

Comment: There's no stdlib.h include so indeed this code might crash and burn if you run it through a dinosaur C90 compiler.

Comment: `realloc(s, sizeof(students) * scount);` --> `s = realloc(s, sizeof *s * (scount + 1)); if (s== NULL) OutOfMemory();`

Comment: @TobySpeight yes, indeed, good catch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
students *mynew= realloc(s, sizeof(students)* (scount+1));
if( mynew != NULL )
    s=mynew;
```

Otehrwise you are having a memory leak. You didn't use the return value of `realloc`.

Don't cast the return type of `malloc`.

As per standard **§7.22.2.35**

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size)
```

> The `realloc` function deallocates the old object pointed to by `ptr` and
>   returns a pointer to a new object that has the size specified by `size`.

It is good not to use the same pointer variable on which you are calling `malloc` because in case it fails you will lose reference to the old one too (unless it is stored by other means).

Also you didn't check the return value of `malloc`.

```
s = malloc(sizeof(students));
if( s == NULL ){
   frpntf(stderr,"%s","Memory allocation failed");
   exit(1);
}
```

Also you should check the return value of `fgets()`.

```
if( fgets(s[scount].name, sizeof(s[scount].name), stdin) == NULL){
     fprintf(stderr,"%s","Error in input");
     exit(1);
}
```

---

Also trying to compile your code it showed this

> ```
> warning: ignoring return value of ‘realloc’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
>          realloc(s, sizeof(students) * scount);
>          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

When compiling try not to ignore any warning messages. It showed the problem you had.

#### Important point: (why `scount+1` in `realloc`?)

When reallocating the general idea is increase the number of students. And for that you need to have extra memory allocated for an student. That's why the `scount+1` in the code.(`realloc`).

---

#### Some other points:

```
while (s[scount].name[index] != '\n')
{
    index++;
}
s[scount].name[index] = '\0';
```

You can do it like this also

```
size_t len = strlen(s[scount].name);
if(len){ 
   s[scount].name[len-1]='\0'; 
}
```

To understand why from standard **§7.21.7.2**

```
char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n,FILE * restrict stream)
```

> The `fgets` function reads at most one less than the number of
>   characters specified by `n` from the stream pointed to by `stream` into
>   the array pointed to by `s`. No additional characters are read after a
>   new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. **A null
>   character is written immediately after the last character read into
>   the array.**

`\0` character was there already in the inputted `string`. You can get the length of it but you know that the one before the `\0` is the `\n` character <sup>**1**</sup> that you entered by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. We are overwriting it with the `\0`.

**1.** This is the usual case but *not the only one*. There are two cases where this might not be the right way to look at the thing.

- The input line has `n-1` or more characters before the `'\n'`. The the one before `\0` will not be the `\n` rather it will be some character inputted by the user.
- The last line is a stream which may not have a `'\n'`. (stdin closed). In that case also the input doesn't contain the `\n`.

So in these cases the idea of removing `\n` would fail.<sub>Discussed in comment. (chux)</sub>

---

#### A better and safe solution than overwriting this way:

```
s[scount].name[strcspn(s[scount].name, "\n")] = '\0';
```

The explanation from the **[link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/180364/basic-shell-in-c/180372#180372)** is that if a `\0` is given as input then we will basically write to  `s[scount].name[SIZE_MAX]` which is not desired.

---

From the standard **§7.24.5.3**

```
size_t strcspn(const char *s1, const char *s2)
```

> The `strcspn` function computes the length of the maximum initial
>   segment of the string pointed to by `s1` which consists entirely of
>   **characters not from** the string pointed to by `s2`.

Comment: "but you know that the one before the \0 is the \n character" -  That is the usual situation.  That is not the case when 1) (pathological case) the input line has n-1 or more characters before the `'\n'` 2) the last line is a stream  may not have a `'\n'`.  (`stdin` closed).

Comment: Thank you a lot! Awesome, it's working. And now I truly better understand the working of pointers. Thank you.

Comment: @chux, ... or when the user presses Ctrl-D after inputting a proper char.  You will receive a non-nl terminated string (of whatever size it results to be)  And that's not the EOF normal situation.

Answer (score 4):

> How to correctly malloc a struct in C ?

```
p = malloc(sizeof *p);
if (p == NULL) Handle_OutOfMemory();
```

> How to correctly re-allocate a struct in C ?

```
void *t = realloc(p, sizeof *p * number_of_elements);
if (t == NULL && number_of_elements > 0) {
  Handle_OutOfMemory();
} else {
  p = t;
}
```

`p` points to some `struct`.  Notice **no coding of that type** in above.

---

OP' primary problem is not using the return value of `realloc()` and allocating 1-too-small

```
// realloc(s, sizeof(students) * scount);
s = realloc(s, sizeof *s * (scount+1));  // or use above code with check for out-of-memory.
```

Comment: "Handle_OutOfMemory", your Camel_CaSe mix is very funny ^^

Comment: @Stargateur It is a "MajorIdentifier_MinorIndentier" model.

Answer (score 2):

`realloc` returns a new pointer that you need to keep:

```
  students* snew = realloc(s, sizeof(students) * (scount + 1));
  if (!snew) {
     free(s); // If there is not enough memory, the old memory block is not freed
     // handle out of memory
  } else { 
     s = snew;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not allocating it back! Take a look at how `realloc` works. You need to assign the pointer back after making the re-allocation like this.

```
if (scount == 0)
{
    s = (students*)malloc(sizeof(students));
}
else
{
    students *temp = realloc(s, sizeof(students) * (scount+1));
    if(temp == NULL){
        free(s);
    }
    else{
        s = temp;
    }
}
```

By Definition, realloc returns a void pointer but you aren't collecting it.

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
```

realloc returns a `NULL` if there's not enough space. So you can re-assign it when you are sure that it is not `NULL`

Just make a small change above and your code works like a charm!

Cheers!

Comment: But don't do it like that - by the time you test `s` to determine whether `realloc()` failed, you've leaked the former value!

Comment: @TobySpeight, my bad. Just focused on giving the answer than checking for corner cases. Thanks anyway.